# How do I find the interrupt vectors used by my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, interrupts

I am using Windows 7 laptop of Dell make. I am trying to find the number of interrupts and interrupt vectors used by my system. I tried with device manager but I was able to find the interrupts and the interrupt levels but no interrupt vectors.

Can someone explain how interrupt handling in windows works? And how can I find out how many interrupts are supported by my system along there vectors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interrupt vectors are a function of the processor, not the OS, and are architecture specific (you can see the x86 implementation [Interrupt Descriptor Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table)).  Windows has specifically prevented program access to the vectors since [Windows Server 2003](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759759%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for x64 systems and attempting to use them will generate a bug check with the stop code 0x109 and shut down the system.

As to the actual handling of interrupts, that is handled in device specific code (drivers).  The documentation of which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The general gist of it is that the hardware generates a DIRQL which is then handled by the corresponding driver's interrupt service routine, implemented as an [EvtInterruptIsr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback function.